# To get exact touch position (from screen coordinates to canvas coordinates) from a scaled canvas

Tags: android, canvas, touch, scale

Hi,

I have an application which zoom/pans the image within screen bounds.
I have custom ImageView class inside my CustomFrameLayout as defined below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

<com.example.panzoomapplication.panzoom.CustomFrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/custom_frame_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        >

<com.example.panzoomapplication.panzoom.CustomImageView
                            android:id="@+id/drawing_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/image"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</com.example.panzoomapplication.panzoom.CustomFrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am scaling canvas in CustomFrameLayout class  using,

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
                        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
                        mScaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
                        calculatePanZoomMatrix();
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                    private void calculatePanZoomMatrix() {
                     mPanZoomMatrix.reset();
                     // scale the view w.r.t to center of the canvas.
                     mPanZoomMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
                     invalidate();
                    }

                    and in ondraw() of CustomFrameLayout,

                     @Override
                     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                         canvas.concat(mPanZoomMatrix);
                     }
```

The canvas zooms well and takes correct touch position when mScalFactor = 1 (or in initial state). But when scaled by a factor greater than 1, the touch event coordinate shifts by a certain amount. I have tried to simulate this issue by drawing a circle at touch position in CustomImageView class.

```
                @Override
                    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                        super.onDraw(canvas);
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setPathEffect(null);
                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        if (mCirclePoint != null)
                            canvas.drawCircle(touchEvent.x, touchEvent.y, 6, paint);
                       }
```

The circle draws well at initial state of canvas (mScalFactor = 1), but shifts its position from actual touch point when scaled by a factor greater than 1. I have tried to fix this issue using matrix as follows,

```
            public float[] getAbsolutePosition(float touchX, float touchY) {
                    float[] scaledPoints = new float[2];
                    scaledPoints[0] = touchX ;
                    scaledPoints[1] = touchY;
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.reset();
                    foat scaleFactor = mCustomFrameLayout.getScaleFactor();
                    float centerX = mCustomFrameLayout.getCenterScaleX();
                    float centerY = mCustomFrameLayout.getCenterScaleY();
                    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, centerX, centerY);
                    matrix.mapPoints(scaledPoints);
                   return scaledPoints;
              }
```

but end up with same problem.

Could you please help me to fix this issue? I have googled a lot but with no perfect solution.*

Comment: use canvas.getMatrix in onDraw, this Matrix and its inversed firm can be used to mapPoints

Comment: how do you obtain touch coordinates?

Comment: @Salauyou : Through onTouchEvent()...

Comment: event.getX() or getRawX() ?

Comment: @Salauyou: event.getX()...

Comment: that's very interesting, because getX() should return coordinate relative to initial canvas, already affected by martix transformations...

Comment: Hi, i think my matrix calculation was wrong. I have changed my  implementation a bit..I have extended TouchImageView for my CustomImageView by Mike Ortiz in github  and applied the solution as suggested by pskink to get the actual scaled matrix...I have applied this inverted matrix to map actual touch  event coordinates..Now its working for me....Thanks pskink...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Canvas to scale, is better to use matrix

to get touch coordinates from image(not screen):

```
void coorImagen(MotionEvent e){
    float []m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] * -1;
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] * -1;
    float scaleX = m[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = m[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
    lastTouchX = (int) ((e.getX() + transX) / scaleX);
    lastTouchY = (int) ((e.getY() + transY) / scaleY);
    lastTouchX = Math.abs(lastTouchX);
    lastTouchY = Math.abs(lastTouchY);

}
```

to get coordinates of screen use:

```
e.getX();
e.getY();
```