# Getting a particular position in canvas after zoom the canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, position, touch, zooming

I need to click on particular item on the canvas while zooming and moving functionalities also enable for canvas. I can calculate the rectangle position while moving the canvas. There I just calculate the touch movement distance by (CurrenTouchXPosition - StartXPosition).

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    int x = (int) event.getX(); 
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    float moveOffsetX = (event.getX() - start.x);
    float moveOffsetY = (event.getY() - start.y);
```

Then,

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d(TAG, "action up");
                secondRectUpperX = secondRectUpperX + moveOffsetX;
                secondRectBottomX = secondRectBottomX + moveOffsetX;
                secondRectUpperY = secondRectUpperY + moveOffsetY;
                secondRectBottomY = secondRectBottomY + moveOffsetY;
```

This can identify the new canvas position of the rectangle. This works perfectly. I can identify the touch event of particular item while moving the canvas by this logic.
  But now i need to calculate the rectangle position relative to the canvas, after zoom the canvas. Whats the maths behind the zooming. If anyone knows please help in this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up with a solution.

I translate my touch position screen coordinates to canvas coordinates.

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float []m = new float[9];
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] * -1;
            float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] * -1;
            float scaleX = m[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
            float scaleY = m[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
            lastTouchX = (int) ((event.getX() + transX) / scaleX);
            lastTouchY = (int) ((event.getY() + transY) / scaleY);
            lastTouchX = Math.abs(lastTouchX);
            lastTouchY = Math.abs(lastTouchY);
```

[Thanks for Andres Cardenas Pardo's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080746/to-get-exact-touch-position-from-screen-coordinates-to-canvas-coordinates-from)

I could able to get the touch position coordinates according to the canvas coordinates. Since i know the coordinates of my drawn object, i check whether the touch position is within the range of drawn object.

```
if((lastTouchX>=firstRectUpperX && firstRectBottomX>=lastTouchX) && (lastTouchY>=firstRectUpperY && firstRectBottomY>=lastTouchY)) {
    isbtn1Clicked = true;
```

}